# How to calculate the total cross section of a QCD process? (qq->gg)

Tags: particle-physics, quantum-chromodynamics, perturbation-theory, singularities, scattering-cross-section

I want to calculate the **total** cross section of various QCD processes (let's go with $q\bar{q}\rightarrow gg$ for this question) at **tree level** for some colliding hadrons at a certain energy (let's go with $pp$ at $\sqrt{s}=14$ TeV like the LHC) but after various days of reading I'm very stuck on how to obtain a finite result. This is what I found:

- The differential cross section for $q\bar{q}\rightarrow gg$ on the center of mass system is:
  $\begin{equation}
  \displaystyle\frac{\mathrm{d}\sigma}{\mathrm{d}\Omega_{\mathrm{CM}}}=\frac{g_s^4}{24\pi^2}\left(\frac{4}{9}\frac{1}{ut}-\frac{1}{s^2}\right)\left(\frac{u^2+t^2}{s}\right)
  \end{equation}$
- **Collinear divergence** - for small angles, $t\rightarrow 0$ and the differential cross section diverges.
- **Kinoshita-Lee-Nauenberg theorem** - This tells us (in QED) that the collinear divergences cancel out with the indistinguishable final states (soft photons). However in QCD this isn't enough since you also have to sum over very close jets and do other stuff since initial and final states aren't free. I have read that this last issue is absorbed into the PDFs.
- **Transverse-momentum dependent PDFs** and **factorisation theorem** - this looks very promising but I haven't found a practical example about how to use them. On the theory side, I have read that it's useful for solving the collinear divergences in hadron-hadron to jets processes, among other cases.
- **Eikonal approximation** - Same as the other case, I've found some notes about the theory but not anything applied. I've seen that when working on high-energy regime and low momentum transfer, you can go to Minkowski light cone coordinates and do some approximations based on that.
- **Gluon reggeization** - Some slides I found said that QCD processes at high energies are always dominated by t-channel reggeized gluons. However I don't think it applies here since there's no tree-level diagram with a gluon on the t-channel.

As a final note, I can use the measurements for the proton PDFs available online. My only "condition" is that I want to use a differential cross section (the one I have shown or another which has the collinear divergence issue fixed). Thanks in advance!